# string index out of range when reading a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I want to read a csv of the following format

```
BX80684I58400;https://www.websupplies.gr/epeksergastis-intel-core-i5-8400-9mb-2-80ghz-bx80684i58400
bx80677g3930;https://www.websupplies.gr/epeksergastis-intel-celeron-g3930-2mb-2-90ghz-bx80677g3930
```

and I use the following

```
contents = []
with open('websupplies2.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
urls = csvf.read()
split_urls=urls.split('\n')

for split_url in split_urls:

    contents.append(split_url[1])
```

but I get

***string index out of range***

I noticed that I can't pass delimiter=';' inside csvf.read(). 
If I change it to

```
csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=';')
```

I get that split is not supported..

thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        print(row[1])
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.websupplies.gr/epeksergastis-intel-core-i5-8400-9mb-2-80ghz-bx80684i58400
https://www.websupplies.gr/epeksergastis-intel-celeron-g3930-2mb-2-90ghz-bx80677g3930
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an explanation.

The problem isn't related with `csv` or something else. The main reason:

> string is shorter than index value. in other words: there is no element by index(`split_url[1]`) in string

I try to explain using just a variable:

```
your_string = 'abc'
print(your_string[0]) # a
print(your_string[1]) # b
print(your_string[2]) # c
# len(your_string) is 3, but you trying to get next item
print(your_string[3]) # IndexError: string index out of range
```

You can fix it using condition(`if len(split_url)...`) but I think that @Rakesh solution is better.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use csv module, here are few [examples](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/reading-csv-files)

```
import csv

csv.register_dialect('myDialect',
delimiter = ';',
skipinitialspace=True)

with open('websupplies2.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, dialect='myDialect')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

csvFile.close()
```